# How to update strings in a list based on condition

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I am stuck in a situation where I have a list and I want to change subnet `/21` to `/24`.

```
x = ['192.168.8.1/21', '192.168.4.36/24', '192.168.47.54/16']
for a in x:
    if "21" in (a[-2:]):
        print(a)
    else:
        print("carry on")
```

Now it's printing right values but how I can change the values of `a[-2:]` `21` to `24` I fail to understand.

Output:

```
192.168.8.1/21
carry on
carry on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change a part of a string as strings are immutable.  But you can replace the string with a corrected version.

```
x = ['192.168.8.1/21', '192.168.4.36/24', '192.168.47.54/16']

# we use enumerate to keep track of where we are in the list
# where i is just a number
for i, a in enumerate(x):
    # we can use a string method to check the ending
    if a.endswith('/21'):
        print('Replacing "/21" in "{}" with "/24"'.format(a))
        # here we actually update the list with a new string
        x[i] = a.replace('/21', '/24')
    else:
        print("carry on")

#output:
Replacing "/21" in "192.168.8.1/21" with "/24"
carry on
carry on
```

And if you check what `x` is now:

```
x
#output:
['192.168.8.1/24', '192.168.4.36/24', '192.168.47.54/16']
```

Comment: You can just do `for i, a in enumerate(x): x[i] = a.replace('/21', '/24')` if you are sure the `/21` pattern appears only where you expect it to (i.e: at the end of the string)

Comment: I wanted to keep the `print` statements from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally change the last two characters of a string in a list using a list comprehension and an if statement:

```
x = [a[:-2] + '24' if a[-2:] == '21' else a for a in x]

print x   # ['192.168.8.1/24', '192.168.4.36/24', '192.168.47.54/16']
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

```
print(a[:-2] + '24')
```

A little bit more flexible would be this:

```
r = {
    '21': '24',
    # '16': '17'
}
x = ['192.168.8.1/21', '192.168.4.36/24', '192.168.47.54/16']
for a in x:
    s = a[-2:]
    if s in r:
        # get replacement
        n = a[:-2] + r[s]
        print(n)
    else:
        print("carry on")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function like this:

```
def change_subnet(ips, from, to):
    for ip in ips:
        if ip[-2] == from:
            yield ip[:-2] + to
        else:
            yield ip
```

which you can use like this:

```
>>> ips = ['192.168.8.1/21', '192.168.4.36/24', '192.168.47.54/16']
>>> list(change_subnet(ips, "21", "24"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to copy the part you are interested in from a, and then concatenate with the end you want :

```
x = ['192.168.8.1/21', '192.168.4.36/24', '192.168.47.54/16']
for a in x:
  if "21" in (a[-2:]):
    print(a)
    a = a[:-2] + '24'
    print(a)
  else:
    print("carry on")
```