# Append letter to end of each string in list in python

Tags: python, string, list, append

I need to make these words past tense by adding either a d or ed to the end of each one on the list, depending on whether the word ends in an 'e' or not. I'm trying to put them in a second list of past tense words.

I'm trying to work with the basic knowledge I've got already. This throws an error at the .append line, saying list indices must be integers not strings. I'm a bit stuck, any thoughts?

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
past_tense = []

for i in words:    
    if i[-1] == 'e':
        past_tense.append(words[i] + 'd')
    else:
        past_tense.append(words[i] + 'ed')
```

Comment: You confuse yourself with naming. Change the loop to `for word in words` and go from there

Comment: `i` is a word, not a number. You can't index into a list with a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update strings in a list based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812711/how-to-update-strings-in-a-list-based-on-condition). Adapting the code to your problem should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your treating `i` like a index with `words[i]`. `i` is the word when you do `for i in words:`. It will be much clearer to replace `i` with `word`. Then you won't get confused with indices and words.

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
past_tense = []

for word in words:    
    if word[-1] == 'e':
        past_tense.append(word + 'd')
    else:
        past_tense.append(word + 'ed')

print(past_tense)
# ['adopted', 'baked', 'beamed', 'confided', 'grilled', 'planted', 'timed', 'waved', 'wished']
```

We could also just use a list comprehension:

```
past_tense = [word + 'd' if word[-1] == 'e' else word + 'ed' for word in words]

print(past_tense)
# ['adopted', 'baked', 'beamed', 'confided', 'grilled', 'planted', 'timed', 'waved', 'wished']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in words:
```

This iterates through each word in the list words. So this is not an integer, `i` is now a string. so `words[i]` will through the error you got.

Working code:

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
past_tense = []

for index,word in enumerate(words):    
    if word[-1] == 'e':
        past_tense.append(words[index] + 'd')
    else:
        past_tense.append(words[index] + 'ed')
```

Comment: He was confused with the index and the element itself in the iteration. I just wanted to remove his confusion and wanted to show a method to do iteration with both index and elements @Jan. Obviously, other answers here are better. I just wanted to let him know, there is something called `enumerate` too.

Comment: Exactly, thank you! I have been having trouble understanding when the index or what's at the index is being accessed, that really cleared that part of it up.

Answer (score 3):

When doing `for i in words` in fact `i` will be one element of the array `words` so a *word*

You don't need the index in the array, just the value

```
for word in words:    
    if word[-1] == 'e':
        past_tense.append(word + 'd')
    else:
        past_tense.append(word + 'ed')
```

Using list comprehension:

```
past_tense = [word + ('d' if word[-1]=='e' else 'ed') for word in words]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make yourself comfortable with list comprehensions:

```
past_tense = [word + ("d" if word.endswith("e") else "ed")
              for word in words]
print(past_tense)
```

Which yields

```
['adopted', 'baked', 'beamed', 'confided', 'grilled', 'planted', 'timed', 'waved', 'wished']
```

---

"Old-style":

```
for word in words:
    if word.endswith("e"):
        past_tense.append(word + "d")
    else:
        past_tense.append(word + "ed")
```

Or even:

```
for word in words:
    suffix = "d" if word.endswith("e") else "ed"
    past_tense.append(word + suffix)
```

Comment: List comprehension with double loop and superfluous inner list? That's going to hurt performance unnecessarily (+ it looks pretty weird since you actually have only one loop).

Comment: @a_guest: Changed it. Was playing around with a variable name before but you were right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for, it just needed a few tweaks (see comments):

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
past_tense = []

for word in words:
# changed i to word, to reflect what the variable will actually contain.
    if word.endswith('e'):
    # endswith is a nice string method that makes the code very readable.
        past_tense.append(word + 'd')
    else:
        past_tense.append(word + 'ed')
```

Result:

```
>>> print(past_tense)
['adopted', 'baked', 'beamed', 'confided', 'grilled', 'planted', 'timed', 'waved', 'wished']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for i in words:`  you are actually setting 'i' to be an actual item (in this case a word) from words list, so as you can see that 'i' is a string and not a integer.

Your error is comes from this line:

```
past_tense.append(words[i] + 'd')
```

Because, as I already said, you can't use 'i' as an index, since it's a string.

So your code would have to be:

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
past_tense = []

for i in words:    
    if i[-1] == 'e':
        past_tense.append(i + 'd')
    else:
        past_tense.append(i + 'ed')
```

Or if you use `for i in range(0,len(words)):` which means 'i' will go from 0 to length of words list -1:

```
words = ["adopt", "bake", "beam", "confide", "grill", "plant", "time", "wave", "wish"]
past_tense = []

for i in range(0,len(words)) :    
    if words[i][-1] == 'e':
        past_tense.append(words[i] + 'd')
    else:
        past_tense.append(words[i] + 'ed')
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers all answer your direct question, but if you're looking for a more general way to determine the past-tense form of a verb (e.g., 'give' to 'gave'), a more nuanced library will be able to handle that with higher accuracy. [NodeBox](https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation) is a good one.

```
python3 -m pip install pattern
```

Then as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942096/how-to-conjugate-a-verb-in-nltk-given-pos-tag), you can use its `en` package to conjugate verbs.

```
from pattern.en import conjugate
past_tense = []

for word in words:
    past_tense.append(conjugate(word, tense='past'))
```